I can't install the package"EdSurvey" in R
I'm trying to install the package "EdSurvey", but this throws a warning:
install.packages("EdSurvey")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/malha/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘Matrix’ is not available

  There is a binary version available but the source version is
  later:
         binary source needs_compilation
EdSurvey  4.0.4  4.0.7             FALSE

installing the source package ‘EdSurvey’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/EdSurvey_4.0.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1027685 bytes (1003 KB)
downloaded 1003 KB

* installing *source* package 'EdSurvey' ...
** package 'EdSurvey' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning messages:
1: package 'car' was built under R version 4.2.3 
2: package 'carData' was built under R version 4.2.3 
3: package 'lfactors' was built under R version 4.2.3 
4: package 'Dire' was built under R version 4.2.3 
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'Matrix' 1.5-1 is already loaded, but >= 1.5.4.1 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'EdSurvey'
* removing 'C:/Users/malha/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/EdSurvey'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘EdSurvey’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\malha\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8Kkm7T\downloaded_packages’

How can I install EdSurvey?

Welcome to SO.  The error message is pretty clear: install RTools - and by implication Matrix. (It looks like you need to update Matrix.)  What happened when you tried to do that?

Matrix is a package that's usually installed by default by R. You are using an older R version (~4.2). You should probably updated your R version which should give you a newer Matrix version.

Thank you, I had previously downloaded (Rtools) but did not notice that it was approved for release
But what remains is a "matrix" that shows this message
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘Matrix’ is not available for this version of R
A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
What to do to make a package"EdSurvey" work?

Rtools is a package with system dependencies, so it must be installed separately. Try this:
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/
Once installed, try again with  with standard install.packages("EdSurvey"). Works for me.
